# Python fails with parsing file using re

Tags: python, regex, encoding

I have a file that is mostly ascii file, but there appear some non-ascii characters sometimes. I want to parse this files and extract the lines that are marked in a certain way. Previously I used sed for this, but now I need to do the same in python. (Of course I still can use os.system, but I'm hoping for something more convenient).

I'm doing following.

```
p = re.compile(".*STATWAH ([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9 ]*):([0-9 ]*) STATWAH.*")
f = open("capture_8_8_8__1_2_3.log", encoding="ascii")
fl = filter(lambda line: p.match(line), f)
len(list(fl))
```

And in the last line I get following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2227: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I remove encoding parameter from the second line, i. e. use default encoding which is utf-8, the error is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2227: invalid start byte
```

Could you help me please what can I do here, except calling sed from python?

UPD.

Thanks to @Wooble I found the answer.

The correct code looks following:

```
p = re.compile(rb".*STATWAH ([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9 ]*):([0-9 ]*) STATWAH.*")
f = open("capture_8_8_8__1_2_3.log", "rb")
fl = filter(lambda line: p.match(line), f)
len(list(fl))
```

I opened file in binary mode and also compile regex from binary string representation.

Comment: Why are you opening the file with the ASCII codec if you know it's not ASCII, or the default UTF-8 if it's not UTF-8? Use the correct encoding, or open it in binary mode (and use a bytestring in the regex...)

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't know about such possibility.